# When is the best time to make a ETH transaction without paying high gas fees?

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-price

Currently the gas prices are 100 gwei at 6AM EST. It would cost me $50 worth of eth to interact with a smart contract. When is the best time and day to do these transactions? Is there some type of chart that shows what time is best and when? The current state of eth is totally unusable unless you deal with large transactions on layer 1.

Comment: Sometimes Friday night-Saturday evening, depending on the timezone, but it is not always true, for example if some NFT decides to airdrop.

Answer (score 0):

The best site to check eth gas fees is:

https://ethgas.watch

It shows the past 7 days gas in a nice chart.

[image]